# Finding the product of i element of an array, such that the product does not contain i

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code i'm working on, i have the concept but i'm trying to implement it, it seems my approach isn't working.

Challenge: I have to product the elements of an array such that the sum of the elements does not contain the value of an i element that is also part of the array.

**Example:** 
Input Array  = [1,2,3,4]
Output Array = [1 => 24, 2=> 12, 3=>8, 4=>6]
Representation: 1 = (2 * 3 * 4 ) = 24, 2 = ( 3 * 4 * 1 ) = 12, 3 =(4 * 1 * 2) = 8, 4 = ( 1 * 2 * 3) = 6

Here's my code below it works but not completely.

```
function sum_array(array $_array){
$_sum = 1; // initilize to 1 to avoid multiplication by 0
$_temp_array = array();
$_result_array = array();

 
  foreach($_array as $keys => $values){
        $_temp_array[$values] = $values; // create a copy of the main array
          
          if($_temp_array[$values] == $values){
              $_sum *= $values; 
            }
             
        $_temp_array[$values] = $_sum;
     
  }

 rsort($_temp_array, SORT_REGULAR);

 foreach($_temp_array as $k => $v){
  $_result_array[$_array[$k]] = $v;
 }

 print_r($_array);
 print '<br/>';
 //print_r($_temp_array);
 print '<br/>';
 print_r($_result_array);
```

}

echo sum_array([1,2,3,4]);

Comment: Side note: that's not a sum, that's a product (sum is the result of addition, product the result of multiplication).

Comment: Oh, i yeah thanks, but basically that's why i highlighted the example for clearer explanation. thanks tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive this with this code :

```
$array = [1,2,3,4];
$output = [];

foreach($array as $a){
    $temp = $array;
    
    $exclude = array_keys($temp, $a);
    
    foreach($exclude as $e){
        unset($temp[$e]);
    }
    $output[$a] = array_product($temp);
    
    
}
var_dump($output);
```

**EDIT**

Without in built fonctionnality :

```
$array = [1,2,3,4];
$output = [];

foreach($array as $a){
    $product = 1;
    
    foreach($array as $t){
        if($t != $a){
            $product *= $t;
        }
        
    }
    
    $output[$a] = $product;
    
}
var_dump($output);
```

output :

```
array(4) {
  [1]=>
  int(24)
  [2]=>
  int(12)
  [3]=>
  int(8)
  [4]=>
  int(6)
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83aac99d698abd415d3701abccc67e187f3d9d5c

Comment: wow, thanks, but can you do this without any built in  functionality?

Comment: i had the concept, but couldn't wrap it up  and also didn't want to use built in functions. nicely done.